# How to create a ToggleButton in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How might I create a ToggleButton in my Blackberry application?

Comment: Is this for a webworks app, or a java app?  Could you describe what you have in mind, or perhaps provide some example images of what you have in mind?

Comment: It's for java app.
I'm considering using BitmapField with different colors.
Or is any other built-in Field.

ToggleButton, I have in mind, the button when it is pressed, it's like embossed inside. Just like Bold button in Office Word. just to make user notice is it pressed or unpressed. Just like on/off buttons. Please check this link. http://java.sun.com/products/jlf/ed2/book/HIG.Controls2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chech this KB article: "[How to - Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0)".

Looks like `LabelledSwitch` is what you need.